# How to connect an 8 module relay with DAQ NI USB 6800?

Tags: usb

I have been trying to figure out how to connect a 8 module relay to a DAQ NI USB 6800 device instead of an Arduino or a Raspberry Pi. Could somebody help me figure out the connections?

Answer (score 1):

You would connect it in exactly the same way - with a wire from one of the digital IO ports to the control input of the relay. Connect ground-to-ground, as you would for the Arduino, and any power that is required for your relay modules.

Comment: hello majenko. thank you for your fast response. i want to bore you with a series of basic questions since i am new at all this. 1) how do i connect devices to my module relay? i have valves, sensors and transducers not to forget a PAP 1600 W power charger. 2) do you know how to apply PLC logic to make a program in lab view? thank you/.

Comment: 1: Treat them just like a switch. 2: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Be sure not to exceed the ratings of the relay contacts.  For your 1600 W charger you will probably need to use the relay board to control a large relay with contacts rated to carry the charger's current.

Comment: If you have to use Labview then it is the PLC ... do the training modules first. The training should cover loops and sequences etc. Then look on the Labview web site and youtube for examples ... explaining Labview in words is horrible.